# What it the logic behind prisons' spatial distribution around the world?

Tags: crime, society, prison

I have created [a project](https://www.kaggle.com/code/saldenisov/prisons-of-the-world-where-do-you-find-them) which shows the distribution of prisons globally. There is likely a rationale behind this distribution.

For instance, why does Switzerland have small prisons while France has larger ones? Additionally, why does Estonia have only 3 prisons compared to Latvia's 8, despite a relatively similar population?

If you have insights on where to initiate an investigation into these questions, your input would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not a duplicate but [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27262/why-does-the-us-prison-system-seem-so-ineffective-when-compared-to-prison-system) discusses varying rates of imprisonment. In a sense there are two questions here, how many people are imprisoned and whether to build large or small prisons, so that tackles the first only. (I suspect money is important in the latter.)

Comment: Is this Q about location?  Or sizing?  And... what do you expect to hear?  An explanation for every country's decisions?  That's a lot of countries, with quite possibly very little commonality in their decision-making and history leading to their present circumstances.

Comment: Re Switzerland: which authority is in charge of building and maintaining prisons. If it is the cantons, it would explain the large number of facilities. Some info I have found in the web seems to point at this.

Comment: Interesting project! On a side note, I would suggest computing the histogram of distances based on the _closest_ prison for a given point, not the distances between _all_ pairs of points...

Comment: There's probably something interesting to be gleaned from the data here, but your map mostly reminds me of https://xkcd.com/1138/

Comment: "There is likely a rationale behind this distribution." Citation needed. It is likely to be a function of path dependent historical accident with no real coherent rationale. Also, the map in the question doesn't mean much without a key.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Oh no, there is more data behind; there is not always the case that if the denser is the region more prisons are there. It is a trend, but not so evident in many countries.

Comment: @mountrix I did pairs to see what it would take to take a prisoner from one prison to another. But you have a point; I can add that as well.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I wanted to hear any insights from the public and wanted to find enthusiasts to join. My data is limited; I need more data on prison sizes, on date of construction, and even calories the prisoners uptake, but for that I need more man-power. For a while, I will stay with the geolocalization business, since for example, in Ghana it is complicated even to find the prisons. In Russian there are more than 800 prisons, that are not on the map (OpenStreetMap or google)

Comment: @ohwilleke the data can be found on kaggle.com

Answer (score 8):

- Beware of statistics with low sample sizes. While 8 is almost three times 3, the absolute numbers are so small that random effects might distort things. And according to [this site](https://www.prisonstudies.org/country/latvia), Latvia has 9 prisons, not 8 ...
- France, Belgium and Austria seem to have a nominal capacity around 300 per site, Germany or Poland have 400, Latvia around 500, England & Wales 700, Lithuania or Russia 800, Estonia 1,000. Outside Europe, the US falls in between at 500 per site. Switzerland has less than 100, which seems to be an outlier for *reasonably* large countries. These numbers describe a rounded average, not a median.
- Estonia has recently merged several sites, which again points to the problem with small number statistics.

Answer (score 5):

The construction of prisons is a political act, governed by both pragmatic and political concerns, e.g.:

- Distance from population centers
- Expected incarceration rates
- Institutional philosophy (correctional vs penal vs warehousing)
- Political and economic advantages

Remember that prisons are not just places for holding prisoners; they are major industries in their own right. I know of townships in the US that have actively petitioned to have prisons placed in their district purely for the boost to their tax-base and local economy, and I have no doubts similar factors play into decisions in other nations.

Comment: It is worth noting (since the image in the question shows Western Europe) that no country in the EU has private prisons (the UK did, but the UK left), so there is no "prison industry" per se. The main outlier being France, where a few secondary tasks are sometimes delegated to private organizations (maintenance, laundry, food, ...), but sworn officers are still responsible for everything else.

Comment: @zdimension: 'Industry' is not synonymous with 'private'.  Whoever might run the prison, the institution itself occupies (taxable) land, hires large numbers of people, contracts with local venders; all its employees need housing, food, amenities, etc. The mere presence of a prison )public or private) *pours* money into the surrounding community.

Comment: @TedWrigley For France it is not obvious, they built here the biggest European prison in Evry new Paris, better than it was somewhere else. There is no need to boost the economy in the Paris region.

Comment: @saldenisov: While trying not to sound too cynical, I have to point out that 'having plenty' rarely stops *anyone* from 'wanting more'.

Comment: @TedWrigley, just for info, https://www.crimeandjustice.org.uk/publications/coal-today-gone-tomorrow-how-jobs-were-replaced-prison-places The article that describes the certain logic of prison establishment in the UK during the last 50 years.